# Facebook Graph API 2.0 Permissions Request Denied

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a notification web-app that has a Post-to-Facebook feature. Until the (Graph) API v2.0, it worked great. A user would authenticate with their Facebook account, put their token into our app, and we'd use that to make posts to their wall/page for them when a new notification was sent.

We have applied for the permissions we need to use on Facebook's new API (publish_pages, publish_actions, manage_pages). We received a notice that our application was rejected, so we re-worded the same application for permissions to try to clarify what we use the permissions for, resubmitted it, but have been rejected again.

An app that does almost exactly the same thing we hope to do was granted these permissions (we know, because we both work with- and compete with- that app). Until we found out that that app can still publish posts to Facebook, we believed that all requests to repost/automatically post on users' behalfs were being denied because of a Facebook policy change.

We can't figure out who to contact or where to appeal the denial of these permissions. This probably isn't the right forum (since this isn't specifically a technical question about the API), but I can't see where to take this issue next.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the Login Review FAQs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/faqs

or otherwise refer to

- https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers

Comment: Actually, yes, and it seems to indicate that what our app does (post automatically to Facebook on users' behalfs) is disallowed.

In addition, I've applied to join the FBDevelopers group several times, have never had my application approved by the mods, and every time I go back, the button says, "Join Group" again. I must be getting rejected? I don't understand that at all.